# How to install MinGW 64 on Windows 10

Tags: windows, installation, mingw, sourceforge

I'm trying to install MinGW64 to get a 64-bit C compiler, but I'm facing difficulties trying to follow online tutorials.

I first downloaded MinGW-w64 for 32 and 64-bit Windows from SourceForge by clicking on the green button saying "Download Latest Version".

But instead of finding an installer, I received a folder named 'mingw-w64-v11.0.0' containing the following subfolders:

- build-aux
- COPYING.MinGW-w64
- COPYING.MinGW-w64-runtime
- mingw-w64-crt
- mingw-w64-doc
- mingw-w64-headers
- mingw-w64-libraries
- mingw-w64-tools

I can't locate any executables or an installer. I already have the 32-bit version installed in 'C:\MinGW.'

How can I proceed to install the 64-bit version? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: This thread was closed thats why I couldn't post as answer, however when I faced this problem, this tutorial helped me: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWC5fVk0QqE&t=187s&ab_channel=BoostMyTool

Comment: Check out this blog post on the subject https://gourav.io/blog/setup-vscode-to-run-debug-c-cpp-code.

Comment: @AwshafIshtiaque, thanks a lot. It solved my frustration around this 1 week as the downloaded through the download button is not works.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Download web installer from here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download

Answer (score 8):

You can get a MinGW-w64 build that requires no installation from http://winlibs.com/, just extract the archive and start using it. The site also explains how to use the compiler from Code::Blocks IDE.